# How do I extract one group from a URL using regex for use in a redirect?

Tags: php, regex

I've read the [Best RegEx Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) and tried to wrap my head around the other answers here on Stack Exchange and just can't seem to get it right. Take these three strings:

`http://www.test.com/newyork/class-schedule`
`http://www.test.com/location/newyork/class-schedule`
`http://www.test.com/location/newyork/training`

I need a regex that will extract the `newyork` from the first string and save it for a replace later, but will NOT match any part of the other strings. Also, for obscure reasons, I can not include `http://www.test.com` as a condition for matching (so I can't use anything before the slash that precedes `newyork`). Note that in this scenario, `newyork` could easily be `chicago`, `atlanta`, or any other city name with no spaces or punctuation.

The only thing I've been able to figure out that isolates only `newyork` in the first string is the following:

`/.*\.com\/(.[^\/]*)\/class-schedule/g`

However, this relies on using the URL first which I can't use.

Any ideas on how to achieve this WITHOUT using the URL?

[EDIT]
To clarify what I'm looking for, I'm trying to take the results from the first string and add "location" to it, still using regex. So:

`http://www.test.com/newyork/class-schedule`

would become

`http://www.test.com/location/newyork/class-schedule`

using something like

`http://www.test.com/location/$1/class-schedule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `~/(\w+)/[-a-z]+?/?(?:\?.*?)*(:?\s|$)~gm`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/3.

So it will use the end of URL instead of the beginning and match only the word between slash 2 and 3 from the end. There can be a query string it will still work.

---

**[EDIT 1]**

I exchanged 2 chars doing typo in the end so it was capturing one extra group: `/(\w+)/[-a-z]+?/?(?:\?.*?)*(?:\s|$)`. here: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/4

If you use `preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);` the result you want (newyork) will be in `$matches[1];`, `$matches[0]` contains everything.

You can see the captures in 'MATCH INFORMATION' panel on regex101 in my example!

---

**[EDIT 2]** after your comment.

If you want to replace the whole url you have to match the whole URL, something like this: `.*?/(\w+)/[-a-z]+?/?(?:\?.*?)*(?:\s|$)` will do in this example. See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/5

---

**[EDIT 3]** Add capturing of last part for replacement.

So as you want to reuse last part you need to add capturing parenthesis: `.*?/(\w+)/([-a-z]+?)/?(?:\?.*?)*(?:\s|$)`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/6

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it appears to match the latter part of all three strings, and not only the first string. Also, the groups seem to be screwy when used for future substitution. See [your updated regex here](https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/2)

Comment: No. it matches only the green part (in regex101 example). You know when you get your matches array, lets say `$matches`, the result you want is in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: I just checked your update, actually if you want to do a replace like this then you need to match all the rest of url, see the update here with the replace: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/5

Comment: Almost there! This works on the replacement, but it's also changing the strings that have `training` to be `class-schedule`. How do we prevent that?

Comment: Here you go! https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/6. Basically you just need to also capture the last part

Comment: Amazing! Now here's the last challenge: is there a way to trigger this ONLY in the case of `class-schedule`? That is to say, there are all kinds of URLs we're using on this site -- I only want to trigger this in the case of `class-schedule`...

Comment: Then you can simplify the regex to this: `.*?/(\w+)/class-schedule/?(?:\?.*?)*(?:\s|$)`. See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/7.

Comment: We're SO close. So in this case, the regex matches both the first phrase and the second phrase. I need it to only match the first phrase (because it's being used to redirect to what ends up being the second phrase, and if it matches both, we end up with an endless loop...)

Comment: Ok so this is what you actually need: `.*?(?<!location)/(\w+)/class-schedule/?(?:\?.*?)*(?:\s|$)` - https://regex101.com/r/4VMazZ/8. In the end the question drifted to be very different! Just for the tip, you will have better help and advice if you give more details in questions ;)

Comment: Thanks very much! That totally did the trick. Sorry that I wasn't more clear in the initial instructions -- I thought I hit the critical points (examples of strings, need to only match the first one, need to store the location for use later, etc.) but obviously needed more specifics. Thanks again for the hard work!!!

Answer (score 1):

Could this work? See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/st83Ya/2).

```
(?<=location\/|\.\w{3}\/|\.\w{2}\/)(?!location).*?(?=\/|$)
```

It matches everything following `.xxx/` or `.xx/` or `location/`. I don't know if one letter domain exist, in this case, you can add `|\.\w\/` to the lookahead at the start of the regex.

- `(?<=location\/|\.\w{3}\/|\.\w{2}\/)` is a lookahead, so it matches the following pattern only if preceded by `location/` or `.xxx` or `.xx`
- `.*?` matches every character (lazy)
- `(?=\/|$)` end match if next character is `/` or on line end

**Note:** If `location` is counted as part of the url, I don't think what you are asking is possible in regex, as the city name could be anywhere in string. If so, then you could have a list of cities and check what part of the url matches one of them.

EDIT: You need the multiline `m` flag so `$` also matches end of line